# Simple netbeans C++ project doesn't compile

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, makefile, cygwin

I installed Netbeans and as C++ compiler I installed cygwin. I made a simple project to test out my installation, this is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message that it gives: http://pastebin.com/jRRh7MPi

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, compile quite fine on ideone. http://ideone.com/MH30Y

Comment: Cygwin is not a compiler, is it? it's a compatibility layer. Based on that output, you're using gcc as a compiler. Make sure it's properly installed and not missing any libs.

Comment: Somehow you are building with `gcc.exe` when you should be building with `g++.exe`. Check project settings, and that you really created a _C++ project_ and not a _C project_.

Comment: Also note that [gcc 3.4.4 is 7 years old](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/). An upgrade might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either explicitly link to C++ standard library, or compile using `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job, I chose gcc instead of g++ as compiler

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau: if this was the right answer to your question, you should mark this answer as accepted with the green tick. Thanks! :)